# How to apply PCA in R?

Tags: r, dataset, data-science, pca

I want to apply PCA to my dataset. In my dataset, not all columns are numeric so I checked which one is numeric. And then ı created a subdataset.

```
pca.dataset <- dataset[,12:55]

sapply(pca.dataset, is.finite)

#remove constant columns
pca.dataset <- remove_constant(pca.dataset)
pca.dataset <- remove_constant(pca.dataset, na.rm= TRUE)

pca <- prcomp(pca.dataset, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

After some of research i tried to is.finite method and got this result:
[image]

And i also got this error:

> Error in svd(x, nu = 0, nv = k) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

How can PCA be applied to this dataset, or is there any way to fix the problem?

Comment: Do a col sum of these booleans to get a result per column, also check if there are missing values in any of the columns.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to do col sum to get a result for each column, i got the result. Three columns of them are not visible. That's the point? So i should use columns that are visible in the sum result? I am gonna check also missing values either.

Comment: If you had no missing values or no infinite values then you would expect to get the same sum for each column. If you get a different sum then some columns have infinite values, if you do not get a sum (NA?) then you probably have some missing values in the column.

Comment: I have checked for missing values using colSums(is.na(pca.dataset)) one column has missing value. Thank you for your help. PCA is working now :)

Comment: `anyNA(DF)` will indicate if there are any NA's in DF and `sapply(DF, anyNA)` will report it by column.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing values in your data. Use `which(!is.na(pca.dataset),arr.ind=T)` to figure out the indices of the rows and columns that have missing values and do something about them.